# Setting up MotionEyeOS (Based on Raspbian) wpa_supplicant is connecting me to the internet, but I can't use the local IP to get to the login screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, motion, wpa-supplicant

So my Zero W is accepting the wpa_supplicant, and connecting to the internet, and is visible on the routers connected devices page with the same IP. However, when using a different device (like Fing on my iPhone) - it's not showing up as a device on the network, probably why I can't get to the login page on the browser of my PC by typing in the IP (192.168.0.97).

Can anyone let me know what's probably causing the issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have client isolation turned on your router?  This ability stops devices talking to each other.  Can you ping it from an other device at all?

Comment: Is 192.168.0.1 the right address for your router?  Is 194.168.40.100 really your ISP's DNS or is that a typo?

Comment: 194.168.40.100 is dear old Virgin Media - bet by the AP has isolation turned on.  My mothers did - took me 10 mins to twig why Pi-Hole did not work!